# WebAssemby char* to Javascript Blob

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I have a project were I want to signal processing in WebAssembly. I can load a wav file using javascript and get the data in / parsed and processed in c++ WebAssembly. I then have a pointer that I can pass back to javascript to access via the heap buffer. But for some strange reason the offset is always wrong. I can see the data in the head.

To read in javascript (to blob for saving):

```
  var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer,Module.getOutputPtr(), Module.getOutputSize())],{type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

And c++ to get the pointer I use:

```
int getOutputPtr()
{
   return (int)(int*)&reader.data;
}
```

Comment: I have a work around where I can do a separate allocation externally (javascript) and pass it in as another pointer to a function that copies the data. This works but requires more RAM and an extra copy operation which I would like to avoid!